# Error While calling Controller using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

this is my controller which i want to call, this controller is located in one solution but in another class library

```
  [HttpGet]
        [Route("Business/GetCountries")]
        public JsonResult GetCountries(string countryName)
        {
            List<countries_model> countrylist = null;
            var myresult = "{'name':'John', 'age':31, 'city':'New York' }";
            return Json(myresult,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

this is my jquery ajax code that call my controller

```
baseUrl = "/Business/GetCountries";

function getCountries()
{
    alert();
    var obj = {};
    obj.countryName = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: baseUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);



        },
        error: function (err) {

            console.log(err);
        }
    });


}
```

and this is my route config

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Business",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Business", action = "GetCountries", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: 1) What's the error? 2) You're not sending any data in the request. 3) Your Route definitions are identical aside from the defaults, so the latter can be removed.

Comment: i have 404 not found error because what i am trying to call is on another class library project

Comment: so you mean that we can not call any controller out side the project?

Comment: To bind controller from external project(dll) you just have to provide proper assemblyResolver

Comment: can u give proper example